# How to Receive emails on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: email, google-compute-engine

I'm able to *send* emails from my instance via sendgrind, but how can I *receive* emails (via Google compute engine)? I'm running an apache server with virtual hosts, and have multiple domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can try install any email server software + pop software + a web mail software in compute engine.
Then configure it to receive email via available ports. You should make a virtual host settings for your web-mail as well.
This will automate user creation for your web-mail under your own domain.